# How do I 'attach' an image in a POST request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, amazon-s3, httprequest

Newbie here. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is to attach an image in a client form, and then send the request to the server. Then, the server will upload to image to an S3 bucket.

Here is the code I have right now. The problem is that the server doesn't 'receive' the image. When I console.log the submitted form, it is undefined.

**Client**

```
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
        setSelectedFile({
      preview: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
      file: event.target.files[0]
    });

    };

    const handleSubmission = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", selectedFile.file);

    
    const paramsForBucketUpload = {
      patientID: 1,
      file: formData,
      recordType: 'IMAGE',
      _contentType: selectedFile.file.type,
      fileExtension: selectedFile.file.name.split('.').pop()
    }

    Physician.uploadFileToPatientDatabase(paramsForBucketUpload);
    };
```

**Server**

```
  static async imageUpload(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    // Some code for uploading the image
  }
```

**The response**

```
{
  patientID: 1,
  file: {}, // This is where the file should be, but it is empty.
  recordType: 'IMAGE',
  _contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  fileExtension: 'jpg'
}
```

Could anyone explain what I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I can’t see any code to do with uploading the file to S3 and so I can’t help you…

Answer (score 0):

2 things here, first you should fix your frontend (append all fields to formData) like below:

```html
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", selectedFile.file);
formData.append("patientID", 1);
formData.append("recordType", 'IMAGE');
formData.append("_contentType", selectedFile.file.type);
formData.append("fileExtension", selectedFile.file.name.split('.').pop());

    
const paramsForBucketUpload = formData
```

and then in your backend, you should should some file upload handler packages like multer or busboy which will help you a lot